# In Phonegap apps, how do you indicate that a Request/Response to the server is occuring?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cordova

Consider a standard HTML app, wrapped in Phonegap, with normal "click" or "touch" events firing requests to the server - and occasionally POST'ing or GET'ing form data to the server - and the WebKit client waiting for a response and then rendering it.

When there are even slight delays in these round-trips (even as low as 1/4-2s for example) users get disoriented that there seems to be "nothing happening" between when they click and when the response begins being rendered.

Is there a standard practice in Phonegap for handling short and/or long response times? I have experimented with changing all standard HREF clicks to AJAX calls, where the AJAX call receives a small HTML piece that JavaScript then just attaches to an existing DIV on the page. During the delay, I can just show a "loading" indicator.

This approach inevitably causes havoc with Javascript on the page, many times rendering future clicks totally non-functional.

I'd be very curious what the standard approach is on this. It seems like a very common use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no "standard practice" per se, many apps (including native ones) use a blocking "spinner" to let a user know that something is loading and to prevent interaction with the "page" while the fetching from the server occurs.

Frameworks like jQuery Mobile have this functionality built in (though I am certainly not suggesting you use jQuery Mobile).

I personally use a jQuery plugin for this in my apps: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

If you are not using jQuery already, you certainly don't want to start just to get the blockUI plugin, so you might want to devise your own. All you really need is a full screen div with a large z-index absolutely positioned so that it blocks interaction while the data is being fetched. Within that div you could place a spinner or a message indicating that activity is occurring and take it away again when the fetching has finished.